# Does conditioning on a random variable yield a random variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, conditional-probability, conditioning

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables and $y\in Im(Y)$ a possible value of $Y$. Is $X|Y=y$ a random variable in the mathematical sense? Or is that just abusing notation?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+random+variable+sigma.

Comment: It is a conditional random variable, but the notation $X\mid Y=y$ is indeed often seen as an abuse of notation. Meanwhile $\mathbb  E[X\mid Y=y]$ would not be seen as an abuse